# Rest Api Code not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a very weird problem that i am facing. So currently i have written a rest api code in regard to my requirement.

Basically, this is what i am doing in the code.

Getting Employee Names from a List A( Example) and then filtering the employee names to get unique values out of it.
But, Currently what is happening is, while one of my developers was working on it, she got the code to make it work as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

Now, when i try to access the same page, i am getting duplicate values in the employee column as shown in the image below.
[image]

How is this possible and i would like to know how would you resolve a problem like this?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
$("input[title^='Project Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Project Name']").after("<select id='ProjectField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");

$("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
});
$("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
    var projects=getAllProjects($(this).val());
    $("#ProjectField").html("<option value=''></option>");
    $.each(projects,function(i,project){
        $("#ProjectField").append("<option value='"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"' pdate='"+project.Planned_x0020_Completion_x0020_D+"'>"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"</option>");
    });
    $("#ProjectField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
}); 
$("#ProjectField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").val($(this).val());
    var pDate=$(this).find("option:selected").attr("pdate");    
    $("input[title^='Planned Completion Date']").val(moment(pDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
});
  })
   function getAllEmployeeNames(){
var results;
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title&$expand=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Id",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
    //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
 }
 function getAllProjects(employeeName){
var results;
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Project_x0020_Name,Planned_x0020_Completion_x0020_D,SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title&$filter=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Id",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
    //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
    }

    function GetUniqueEmployee(){
    $.ajax( {
        method: 'GET',

        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title&$expand=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Id&$filter=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title ne null&$top=4000",

        contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            var arr = [],listItemInfo ;                
            for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){                                 
                 arr.push(data.d.results[i].SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader.Title);                   
            }

            arr = $.unique(arr);                
             $.each(arr,function(i,employee){       
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+employee+"'>"+employee+"</option>");

                 });                

        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(e);
        },
    });
}
  GetUniqueEmployee();
```

Comment: If you would like help debugging some of your code, it would be very helpful to see the actual code in question.  We can't begin to speculate about what might be going wrong without seeing what you are actually trying to do! :)

Comment: Yes, please share the code.

Comment: @DylanCristy Hi, i have added the code in the post, you can take a look into it.

Comment: Do not forget to empty the values of dropdown each time you are calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

How it is possible:

I think the issue is that you are using `jQuery.unique()` to try and get the unique employee names.

From the [jQuery documentation for `unique()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) (emphasis mine):

> Description: Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the
>   duplicates removed. Note that ***this only works on arrays of DOM
>   elements, not strings*** or numbers.

How to resolve:

Use some other method to filter out the unique names, and do not use `jQuery.unique()`.

Comment: but it should have not given the results to my other developer than right?

Comment: Theoretically true, however there are other things that could factor in to their getting different results than you: a) are you sure they are running the same code as you, and not a cached version of some older js file that filters for unique names in a different way?  Or maybe your version is the older cached version? b) do they have the same permissions to the list that you do?  It might be possible that they get different results because the response they get from the ajax call has been security trimmed differently than your response?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below to check if it works.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Project Name']").after("<select id='ProjectField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");

    var employees=getAllEmployeeNames();
    $.each(employees,function(i,employee){
        $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+employee.SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader.Title+"'>"+employee.SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader.Title+"</option>");
    }); 
    $("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
    $("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
        var projects=getAllProjects($(this).val());
        $("#ProjectField").html("<option value=''></option>");
        $.each(projects,function(i,project){
            $("#ProjectField").append("<option value='"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"' pdate='"+project.Planned_x0020_Completion_x0020_D+"'>"+project.Project_x0020_Name+"</option>");
        });
        $("#ProjectField option").each(function() {
            $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
        });
    }); 
    $("#ProjectField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Project Name']").val($(this).val());
        var pDate=$(this).find("option:selected").attr("pdate");    
        $("input[title^='Planned Completion Date']").val(moment(pDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
    });
})
function getAllEmployeeNames(){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title&$expand=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
function getAllProjects(employeeName){
    var results;
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Project_x0020_Name,Planned_x0020_Completion_x0020_D,SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title&$filter=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Title eq '"+employeeName+"'&$expand=SC_x0020_Team_x0020_Leader/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are not removing duplicates from the Drop down. Thus, this code would definitely give me duplicates in my drop down.

Comment: the drop down value shows as undefined.

Comment: The $("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    }); code not working?